# Finding the 'Most Improved' in linq

Tags: linq-to-sql

The following code is what i used to identify the Top 10 earning items

```
var top = (from m in db.Stats
           where m.Item.AccountID == AccountID
           && m.DateTime >= month
           && m.DateTime < month.AddMonths(1)
           group m by m.Item into g
           orderby g.Sum(p => p.Earnings) descending
           select g.Key).Take(10).ToArray();
```

I need to identify which item has improved the most (%) when comparing 2 different months.  The Data available is only daily totals.  I might need to filter out items which are below a certain number of 'Visitors' i.e. where

```
m.Visitors >= 20
```

What is the best way to do this in Linq-Sql?

Answer (score 0):

If you split the query into two distinct groups, current month (or time period) and previous month (or time period) it should be easier to manage. For clarity I'm using a private class to keep the results we're interested in. You may be able to use an existing class instead. Or, the compiler might even be smart enough to realize that the properties are identical and thus generate the same anonymous class for both queries.  In any event...

```
private class C {
    public object Key { get; set; }

    public object Earnings { get; set; }
}

var thisMonth = (from m in db.Stats
                 where m.Item.AccountID == AccountID
                 && m.DateTime.Month == month
                 group m by m.Item into g
                 select new C { g.Key, g.Earnings });

var lastMonth = (from m in db.Stats
                 where m.Item.AccountID == AccountID
                 && m.DateTime.Month == month.AddMonths(-1)
                 group m by m.Item into g
                 select new C { g.Key, g.Earnings });
```

From here it's a matter of combining the results to calculate percent gain or loss between the two sets.  Once that's done you can sort by highest gains to get your top n.